# how to create a new folder inside a folder using IFolder or IResources interfaces in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wanted to create some folders inside a folder in my eclipse plugin project programmatically using IResources or IFolder interfaces methods. And then I want to move the files of parent folder inside newly created folder/s...

Comment: Show what u have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder with something like:

```java
IFolder folder = container.getFolder("folder name");

folder.create(false, true, progressMonitor);
```

where `container` is the folder or project containing the new folder.

Move resources using

```java
IResource resource = .... resource to move

IPath destinationPath = folder.getFullPath().append(resource.getName());

resource.move(destinationPath, false, progressMonitor);
```

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 . It works fine But moving of files from this way is taking too much time ... Is there any other way by which we can do it more efficiently ...

Comment: Enclosing the code in a `WorkspaceModifyOperation` or using a `WorkspaceJob` might speed things up a bit, but I don't know of anything that will run significantly faster.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343564/how-to-create-linked-resources-under-virtual-folder-programmatically-in-eclipse @greg-449