# how to create linked resources under virtual folder programmatically in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to create linked resources under my virtual folder

```
    Folder folder = modelFolder.getFolder("Script_include");
    folder.create(IResource.VIRTUAL, false, null);
    IFile newFile = folder.getFile("virtual");
    newFile.createLink(location, IResource.NONE,null);
```

I am getting virtual folder but not able to create linked file under it.

Comment: I think you should be specifying `true` for the 'local' flag on the folder create.